# Clojure: Implementing Seqable for an existing java class

Tags: class, interface, clojure

I am trying to make a core java class implement an interface.
I am trying something along the lines of:

```
(extend-protocol clojure.lang.Seqable
  java.lang.Integer
  (seq [this] (seq (str this))))
```

but this does not seem to work because Seqable is just an interface and not a protocol.
Is it possible to make `(seq 123)` work? how was `seq` implemented for java.lang.Strings?

proxy also does not seem capable of doing this.

I know I must be missing somethnig really obvious here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. `clojure.lang.RT/seqFrom` has [special cases](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L480) for a number of java builtin types, like Collection and String, and you can't add your own for classes that don't implement Seqable directly.

Comment: Thank you, I wonder whether it would have been possible when clojure was designed to make Seqable a protocol or whether it really had to be a special case.

Comment: @WuHoUnited When Clojure was originally implemented, they did not have protocols. My understanding though, was that they used them with great success when implementing Clojurescript.

Answer (score 0):

If the java class implements Iterable, and is wrapped in `seq`, you could use it as a sequence, with certain [restrictions](http://clojure.org/sequences).